# What does variable:expression mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

When I type `aaa: print(1)` in Python 3.6, it will print `1` without any error.

I want to know what variable:expression means in Python.

I Googled and cannot find any documentation related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variable annotation, as described in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/). By running that expression, you've annotated the type of `a` to `None`, the return value of the `print` call, which doesn't make much sense.

You can see this by printing the `__annotations__`, a dictionary that holds the relation between names-types for a module (in your case, the module will probably be `__main__`):

```
print(__annotations__)
{'aaa': None}
```

Python doesn't do anything with these, it simply executed the `print(1)` (resulting in the output of `1` you see) expression and uses the return value of that call to annotate the name `a`. It's up to type-checkers, like `mypy`, to use them for their own purposes.

Comment: Is it a python 3.6 thing? I don't see it in 3.5.2

Comment: @RickyHan yup. You should get a SyntaxError in 3.5.2 (and `__annotations__` for a module don't exist, either)